# select tab item on hover while in drag-and-drop operation in SWT

Tags: drag-and-drop, swt, tabitem, mousehover

I need to select tab items from a SWT tab folder while in a drag-and-drop operation on hover, just like windows does with task bar buttons. My solution can be platform dependent (Windows).

Unfortunately mouse track events do not fire while in DND operations. I decided to implement myself the hover event. I get some mouse events with the dragOver event and I know that the area of the hover zone is the same as the double click area and can be obtained using GetSystemMetrics. However, for the hover delay, I can only seem to be getting it from the registry. It is OK to call some native functions, but the registry seems a bit too extreme.

Do you have any other solutions, or at least some API to find the hover delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for hover time see SPI_GETMOUSEHOVERTIME in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: That is what I was searching for. I also realized that the mouse does not have to stay in the hover rectangle for a taskbar button to get pressed when in drag and drop mode. However the time seems to be the same as the hover time.